# Does Stack Exchange prevent cheating with "fake" accounts?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting, ethics, multiple-accounts

I've been thinking how easily a user could create a fake account to upvote all his own questions/answers. I didn't think of doing it myself; I like to win my reputation the right way, but I'm sure there are a lot of people who would do that.

Does Stack Exchange prevent this in any way?

Comment: Actually, two candidates in the ongoing [moderator election](http://stackoverflow.com/election) withdrew their nominations after it became public that they had practiced cross-voting through sock-puppets in the past. Don't do this at home, kids!

Comment: Shame on them!!

Comment: yeah. Although I would tend to forgive stuff like that after a year or two, if they've evolved into fine community members since then... But vote fraud is obviously a big stain on your jacket, no matter *when* it took place

Comment: I was about to ask this question for a long time and never got to it. Thanks +1

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That is usually referred to as sock puppet accounts, and yes, Stack Exchange does have measures to prevent them from doing any real harm.

See the [Vote Fraud and You](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/) and [More Voting Anomalies](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/more-voting-anomalies/) posts on the blog.